# MySQL cursor does not loop only return the first record

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying a sample SP. This SP does not loop. Trying to figure what where the problem is. Any help is appreciated

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `DB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `build_email_list`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `build_email_list`()
BEGIN 
  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";  

  -- declare cursor for employee email
  DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `email` FROM `people`;

  -- declare NOT FOUND handler
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN email_cursor;

  get_email: LOOP    
    FETCH email_cursor 
    INTO  v_email;   

    IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
      LEAVE get_email;
    END IF;

    -- print list
    SELECT v_email;  
  END LOOP get_email;

  CLOSE email_cursor;    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s5kfESjSyxTAmbtLdWXqE3/0).

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have a version issue it seems. The one works on www.db-fiddle.com doesn't work in my version. Thanks lot for the support